Process execution from c# program having argument parsing error?
I have a C# program I'm working on where I want to have a predefined dictionary list of playlist names (key) and a corresponding YouTube playlist link (value), which I iterate through to feed to yt-dlp.exe to generate a full list of each playlists' video information.
I can get the process to start, but it always throws an error partway through on what seems like a URL parsing issue. I tried taking it out of the iteration loop but it's still happening. The related code (with error logging logic) so far:
        var operatingDir = @"C:\Users\path-to-dir-goes-here\";
        

        var videoPlaylists = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        
        videoPlaylists["alpha"] = "https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLrhpb4TQr-uKzxOB1C_9x-Ysrj2WRMZN_";
        videoPlaylists["bravo"] = "https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLcLtbK8Nf64InyudI1rnYwwRbCr08yup_";
        videoPlaylists["charlie"] = "https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLS9Gv3hDYt_Uh_bI6m2S20siUfPUk1I1b";
        

        var playbackIndex = new Dictionary<string, double>();
        string ytDlpPath = operatingDir + "yt-dlp.exe";
        string ytDlpArgs = "";
        
        
            ProcessStartInfo runYtDlp = new ProcessStartInfo();        
            runYtDlp.FileName = @ytDlpPath;
            ytDlpArgs = "--skip-download --ignore-errors --flat-playlist --playlist-random --force-overwrites --print \"https://www.youtube.com/embed/%(id)s?controls=0&autoplay=1&cc_load_policy=1&cc_lang_pref=en    %(title)s   %(duration)s\" \"" + videoPlaylists["alpha"] + "\" > \"" + operatingDir + "alpha" + ".txt\"";
            runYtDlp.Arguments = ytDlpArgs;
            
            
            Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            
            process.StartInfo = runYtDlp;
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;

            process = Process.Start(runYtDlp);
           
            process.WaitForExit();
            Console.ReadKey();

yt-dlp always gets about 80 lines into writing to the file when this error hits:
ERROR: [generic] '>' is not a valid URL. Set --default-search "ytsearch" (or run  yt-dlp "ytsearch:>" ) to search YouTube
ERROR: Unable to handle request: Unsupported url scheme: "c" (requests, urllib, websockets, curl_cffi)

I don't think it's yt-dlp itself because when I input the arguments directly in the command line it runs fine. Am I formatting my argument string wrong or something?

The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/78380519/10024425

@user246821 Hm, now I'm not getting any response or logging at all, but the playlists still aren't being generated.

Not really a direct solution, but since yt-dlp is made to run from the command line, I switched to System.Diagnostics.Process.Start() instead of trying to use ProcessStartInfo(), and that worked:
    var operatingDir = @"C:\Users\path-to-dir-goes-here\";
    
    var videoPlaylists = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    
    videoPlaylists["alpha"] = "https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLrhpb4TQr-uKzxOB1C_9x-Ysrj2WRMZN_";
    videoPlaylists["bravo"] = "https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLcLtbK8Nf64InyudI1rnYwwRbCr08yup_";
    videoPlaylists["charlie"] = "https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLS9Gv3hDYt_Uh_bI6m2S20siUfPUk1I1b";
    
    
    var playbackIndex = new Dictionary<string, double>();
    string ytDlpPath = operatingDir + "yt-dlp.exe";
    string ytDlpArgs = "";
    

    foreach (var key in videoPlaylists.Keys)
    {            
        ytDlpArgs = "/K yt-dlp --skip-download --no-abort-on-error --flat-playlist --playlist-random --print \"%(id)s,\"%(title)s\",%(duration)s\" \"" + videoPlaylists[key] + "\" > \"" + operatingDir + key + ".txt\"";
        
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("CMD.exe",ytDlpArgs);
    }

